# Replace values with split in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database like this:

```
X_MA2_period=4.4 ,sh2=2 ,Edu_km_hl=8.4 ,Edu_km_sd=5.6 ,Edu_km_sr=5.6 ,Edu_km_v1440=0.6
X_MA2_period=4.4 ,sh2=2 ,Edu_km_hl=8.4 ,Edu_km_sd=5.6 ,Edu_km_sr=5.6 ,Edu_km_v1440=0.6
X_MA2_period=5.8 ,sh2=2 ,Edu_km_hl=9 ,Edu_km_sd=5.6 ,Edu_km_sr=5.8 ,Edu_km_v1440=0.64
X_MA2_period=4 ,sh2=5 ,Edu_km_hl=3.2 ,Edu_km_sd=5.6 ,Edu_km_sr=9 ,Edu_km_v1440=0.5
```

4413 rows x 52 columns

I need to put left side of "=" as name of each column (ex.: X_MA2_period) and right side as list of values in that column. I tried this:

```
lista_colunas = []
for i in range(0, df.shape[1]):
    lista_colunas.append(df.iloc[0][i].split('=')[0])
df.columns = lista_colunas
```

This first part is ok. But...

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row[50] = row[50].split('=')[1]
    print(row[50]) # I tried print to see if is replaced, and it is. But...

print(df.iloc[0][50])
print(df)
```

And all cells have old value, before split... Any help will be welcome!

Comment: Please paste the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())` before you run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# get columns
columns = [v.split('=')[0] for v in df.loc[0]]

# Keep the values to the right of the '=' in the columns
for c in df.columns:
    df.loc[:, c] = df.loc[:, c].str.split('=').str[1]

# Rename the columns
df.columns = columns

df.head()
```

The output is:
[image: Code output]

Comment: Thank you! But I receive this message: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/MT4_Gerando_set_from_report.py", line 26, in <module>
    columns = [v.split('=')[0] for v in df.loc[0]]
  File "C:/MT4_Gerando_set_from_report.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    columns = [v.split('=')[0] for v in df.loc[0]]
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I assume it has to do with the data type in your dataframe. I used the example you shared and imported the data as strings. Are you converting the data to numpy arrays at any point in your code? That might not be necessary with this code.

Comment: Yes, it is a pandas dataframe read from txt file. Numpy not used (nor imported). 

In the file data (txt), first 7 columns are named (each name is str) and have float values each one. Last 8th-52th column are non-named and have alphanumeric data each one. I filled 8th-52th columns with string part before "=".

Comment: Then you probably need to limit the code to the columns with no name (8 - 52) and leave the first 7 as they are. Do you need help how to do that?

Comment: Thank you very much! This solve completely!